# Using the random() in LiveCode

Tags: random, livecode, high-level

I have an issue with using

the random defined function in livecode.

Here is a code snippet:

```html
// 97 -> 122 = lower case...
put random(97,122) into randASCII
```

The program is to create an order number, the order number consists of the first
character of the first name, first character of last name, random number between
1 and 9, and a random ASCII value between 97 and 122 (the lower case characters.)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is not totally clear, I believe what you want is

```
 put numtonativechar(randomInRange(97,122)) into randASCII
```

EDIT: in LiveCode to generate a random number between 2 numbers you need this function first

```
function randomInRange lowerLimit,upperLimit
   return random(upperLimit - lowerLimit + 1) + lowerLimit - 1
end randomInRange
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming you have your list of names in fld 1:

```
on mouseUp
  put fld 1 into temp
  repeat with y = 1 to the number of lines of temp
    put char 1 of word 1 of line y of temp & char 1 of last word of line y of temp & random(9) & numToChar(96 + random(26)) into line y of orderList 
  end repeat
  answer orderList
end mouseUp
```

Comment: I see the earlier comment about getting a random number limited by a maximum and a minimum. Several ways to do this, but I like the one in the above reply:

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a note here that 9007199254740993 is the max random number from which LC can select from.  Its known as the last safe int.

Answer (score -1):

If we have the limits. We just have to look for the difference between them. That is the parameter that we pass to the random () function and then we add the lower limit to it.

```
function randomInRange lowerLimit,upperLimit
   return  lowerLimit + random(upperLimit - lowerLimit)
end randomInRange
```

Comment: Looks like your answer is wrong. See Makeshyft_Tom's answer.